# Applying transformations or joining conditions to achieve the result in pyspark or hive

Tags: sql, pyspark, hive, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Given two tables or dataframes. One will be having datasets and corresponding tables. Other will be having source and target.
I need a solution for the below condition:
Once we find ft.dataset = st.source, we need to replace ft.table in st.source and neglect the remaining records.

For example: Here in first block of second table which is from seq_no 1 to 6, we have a match at Abc, so we replaced with db.table1 and neglect the remaining records in that block. Similarly we need to do the same for each and every block of second table.
Note that Target is same in all the rows of second table.
Please help me with a possible solution in pyspark or Hive.

First table(ft):

```
Dataset |   Table
_________________
Abc           db.table1
Xyz           db.table2
Def           db.table3
```

Second table(st):

```
Target| seq_no| source
______________________
A             1           A
A             2           B1
A             3           C1
A             4           D1
A             5           Abc
A             6           Xyz
A             1           A
A             2           B1
A             3           C1
A             4           D1
A             5           Def
A             6           Abc
A             7           Xyz
```

Expected output:

```
Target| seq_no | source
_______________________
A             1           A
A             2           B1
A             3           C1
A             4           D1
A             5           db.table1
A             1           A
A             2           B1
A             3           C1
A             4           D1
A             5           db.table3
```

Answer (score 1):

In Hive, you can use a left join to search for a match in the first table, and a window `min()` to identify the sequence of the first match

```
select target, seq_no, source
from (
    select 
        st.target, 
        st.seq_no, 
        coalesce(st.source, ft.table) as source,
        min(case when ft.dataset is not null then st.seq_no end) over(partition by st.target) first_matched_seq_no
    from st 
    left join ft on ft.dataset = st.source
) t
where first_matched_seq_no is null or seq_no <= first_matched_seq_no
order by target, seq_no
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it's not working as expected. It's always giving seq_no as one in output and not even replacing the source in st. And it's giving the output where seq_no is one and not considering the remaining records.

Comment: Target| seq_no | source
    _______________________
    A             1           A
    A             1          A

Comment: I mentioned the output coming with ur query. Which is not expected. Can you please update the query and send. Please have a look at the expected output I mentioned in the question.